# I'm not sure how to answer this and I don't even know what type of math it is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm studying for a finals about probability distribution with Z-table and I got to this part in the example of my lecturer and I have no idea how she arrived to this answer, I've been staring at it and scratching my head for a good 30 minutes and still don't know how she got it.
I assume this is probably some basic stuff from high school that I just forgot xD, so please help this stupid college student out haha

```
-2.33 = h-172/8
h = 153.4
```

How did she get 153.4?

Comment: Presumably `h-172/8` means $\frac{h-172}8$ and not $h-\frac{172}8$.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know how to write a fraction sorry about that :/

Comment: Can you solve $-2=x/4$ or $-2=(x-15)/4$?

Comment: @Arthur In fact , in this case, the result is correct when rounded to one digit after the decimal point.

Comment: @TedShifrin I cannot, this seems like some basic math stuff, it's so embarrassing that I can't even solve it. Please help this poor guy out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowledge that is commonly missing in college is *fractions* and solving *equations* with a variable. Unfortunately they are assumed to be known, so some dedicated training with them may be required.

I'll step you through the process for this one.
$$\begin{aligned}
-2.33 &= \frac{h-172}{8} \\
-2.33 \times 8 &= \frac{h-172}{8} \times 8 & \text{Cancel division by 8}\\
-2.33 \times 8 &= h-172\\
-2.33 \times 8 + 172 &= h-172 + 172 & \text{Cancel subtraction of 172}\\
-2.33 \times 8 + 172 &= h &\\
h &=-2.33 \times 8 + 172 = 153.36 \approx 153.4\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I knew it was just a basic equation! xD Thanks a lot! I'm finally able to understand it now